# Convert datatime column to 18-digit LDAP timestamp

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file with AD users and their accountExpires attribute. The accountExpires values are currently in human readable format, but I want to convert it into 18-digit LDAP format so that I can import the file to change the date. I am using pandas to read and modify the file before importing.

```
Date time in the file - 2001-06-21  01:00:00 AM
Desired output - 126375588000000000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`11644473600` = number of seconds between Jan 1601 and Jan 1970 (unix time)
multiplied by `10000000` to convert it to `100ns unit`

```py
import datetime
df['LDAP'] = df['datetime'].apply(lambda x: (((x-datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds())+11644473600)*10000000)
```